# is function differentiable iff directional derivative is linear

Tags: multivariable-calculus

#### Original definition

> A function $f: A \to \mathbb{R}^n$, $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^m$ is differentiable at a point $\mathbf a \in \mathbb R^m,$
>   if there is a linear transformation $T$ such that
>   $$
> \lim_{\lVert \mathbf h\rVert \to 0}
> \frac{f(\mathbf a+\mathbf h)-f(\mathbf a)-T_a(\mathbf h)}{\lVert \mathbf h\rVert} = \mathbf 0.
> $$

#### My definition

> A function $f: A \to \mathbb{R}^n$, $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^m$ is differentiable at a point $\mathbf a \in \mathbb R^m,$
>   if there is a linear transformation $T$ such that for any unit vector $\hat u$
>   $$
> \lim_{t \to 0}
> \frac{f(\mathbf a+t \hat u)-f(\mathbf a)}{t} = T_a(\hat u).
> $$

#### Question: is there any difference between original definition and my definition

In the original definition, $\mathbf h$ can approach to $\mathbf 0$ by any trajectory; In my definition it can only be approached from certain direction, so my definition is weaker than the original definition. Substitute $\mathbf h = t \hat u$ to the original definition will get my definition.

If my definition is not true, can somebody provide a counter example ?

One may already noticed that
$$
\partial_{\hat u} f (a) = T_a(\hat u)
$$
Since $T$ is linear, we can assume (here $\nabla f$ is just a function, it happens to be equal to the gradient if exist):
$$
T_a(\hat u) = \hat u \cdot \nabla f(a)
$$
So my definition can be written as:
$$
\partial_{\hat u} f (a) = \hat u \cdot \nabla f(a) \Leftrightarrow f\text{ is differentiable at }a
$$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For a counterexample try
$$
f:\mathbb{R}^2 \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}
$$
with
$$
f(x,y) = \left\{
   \begin{array}
     11 &\text{if  } \:\:x=y^2\:\: \text{ and  }\:\:(x,y)\not=(0,0)\\
     0 & \text{otherwise}
   \end{array}
   \right.
$$

I don't want to prove everything for you. Try to imagine how this function looks like, why it's not differentiable in $0$ (by general definition) and why partial derivatives exist on all directions (following your definition).

EDIT:

Your intuition is very good. The difference between the original definition of differentiability, and the one you proposed is in the fact that the original definition allows $h$ to approach the point $a$ in any trajectory, while you allow it only on linear trajectories.

This counterexample is a function that is $0$ everywhere, except on a small set $A=\{(x,y)\:|\:x=y^2\} \setminus\{(0,0)\}$ where it is equal to $1$. Looking at the function on this curve, it is obviously not continuous in $0$. But it has directional derivatives in all directions in $0$, since for every direction $\hat u$, the point $t\hat u$ is inside $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus A$ for $t$ small enough.

Comment: You'll note that this function isn't even continuous in 0.

Comment: It doesn't satisfy my definition, my definition requires directional derivatives exist on all directions **and** they are linear.

Comment: The directional derivatives are 0, aren't they? That's as linear as it gets.

Comment: Ahh... I got it.